# Adding a number to an undefined value

Tags: javascript

In the JS example:

```
 var test;

 function test () {
     var t = test + 1;
     alert(t);
 }
```

I am trying to make a counter but if I set `test` to `0`, it still always gives me `1`. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am activating the function through a button.

Comment: What is it that you expect to happen? If you never change `test` why would you expect anything different to happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *should* define `test` as `0` to begin with so that it starts out as an object of type `Number`. Adding numbers to `undefined` results in `NaN` (not-a-number), which won't get you anywhere.

So now to address your issue of why the number never goes past `1`, the first mistake is that you actually don't increment the value of `test` in your code, you just assign the result of temporarily adding `1` to it to `t` before `alert()`ing that result. There's no mutation of `test` here. Use a pre- or post-increment operator or set the result of `test + 1` back to `test` to update it.

Secondly, you should probably not have a function and a local variable named the same, it just confuses things.

Taking all of these into account, we get:

```
var test = 0; // Now test is a Number

function testIncrementOne() { // name change to prevent clashing/confusing
    var t = ++test;    // pre-increment (adds 1 to test and assigns that result to t)
    // var t = test++; // post-increment (assigns the current value of test to t 
                       // and *then* increments test)
    alert(t);
}
```

Or just:

```
 function testIncrementOne() {
    alert(++test);
}
```

Comment: Haha i was 1 min too late!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is this:

```
var test = 0;

 function incrementTest() {
     test = test + 1;
     alert(test);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't in control of *test*, you might do something like:

```
// Test if test is a number, if not, convert it
if (typeof test != 'number') {
  test = Number(test);
}

// If conversion resulted in NaN, set to a default
if (isNaN(test) {
  test = 0;
}

// Now it's safe to do addition
test += 1
```

Of course that is all pretty tedious and can be replaced with:

```
test = (+test || 0) + 1;
```