# Canvas API - why would all of the count values be "undefined" for rating_sum?

Tags: javascript, api, google-sheets, canvas-lms

I need to accomplish a (seemingly) simple task using a Google Sheet and data that I extract from [Canvas](https://community.canvaslms.com/)

**Determine the discussion post like count by student**

For example:

- Student A posts to a discussion board
- Student B hits the like button on Student A's post
- I need to see a count of 1 for Student B's action

This is what I have done so far...

I found these two examples and used them as my starting point:

[How to Count Student Discussion Posts](https://community.canvaslms.com/groups/canvas-developers/blog/2016/01/02/how-to-count-student-discussion-posts)

- This works flawlessly
- I am able to count student discussion board posts
- I verified that the counts are accurate
- Below is the code snippet I am working with

```
if (typeof users[userId] !== 'undefined') {
  if (typeof counts[userId] === 'undefined') {
    counts[userId] = 1;
  }
  else {
    counts[userId]++;
  }
}
```

[Extracting Discussion Post Likes By Student?](https://community.canvaslms.com/thread/34180-extracting-discussion-post-likes-by-student)

- This is what I am trying to solve for
- Below is the code snippet I am working with

```
if (typeof users[userId] !== 'undefined' && typeof entries[entry].rating_sum !== 'undefined') {
  if (typeof counts[userId] === 'undefined') {
    counts[userId] = entries[entry].rating_sum;
  }
  else {
    counts[userId] += entries[entry].rating_sum;
  }
}
```

Initially, this returned no results...which was strange because I have verified manually that there are in fact a number of likes for student posts...and my first test that just counts all discussion board posts returns an accurate count.

I adapted the code to return everything regardless of the `entries[entry].rating_sum` value

```
if (typeof users[userId] !== 'undefined') {
  if (typeof counts[userId] === 'undefined') {
    counts[userId] = entries[entry].rating_sum;
  }
  else {
    counts[userId] += entries[entry].rating_sum;
  }
}
```

What I am seeing is that all `entries[entry].rating_sum` values are 'undefined'

I am not sure how to determine the root cause - I believe the code is working as expected

Your insights are appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Am not quite sure if this array counts[userId] has been initialized you might add rating_sum to "undefinded" values (mb counts is undefined). Maybe you should loop counts first before you do this and set all values to 0.

[Adding a number to an undefined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738127/adding-a-number-to-an-undefined-value)